# trying to return a dict, get none instead

Tags: python, function, dictionary, oop, local-variables

I'm trying to create a python program that automatically generates class files, given input in a specific format. To simplify storage and parsing of data, i defined a class called Class_Dict which contains the specifications for a single class. when inputted, the data looks like:

```
class name : attr1, attr2, attr3 : method1, method 2
```

and the machine understands it as:

```
{"class_name" : ['attr1,attr2,attr3', 'method1,method2']}
```

## Note: I call the object "Class_Dict", but its more fair to call it a key-value pair. I want to stress that- the class dict object should be distinguished from the container (also a dictionary), which can hold many key value pairs, each specifying a new class to be generated.

So, in order to deal with inheritance, i defined a syntax for representing it, and a function which parses the input format and creates class_dict objects. Basically, it loops over each key value pair in the class_container dictionary, and if it has a ">"  in it (designates a parent child relation), then it calls the inheritance function on that entry. The inheritance function takes a entry which details an inheritance hierarchy and builds the appropriate classes. for example, if we have:

`classA, classB > classC : A1, A2 / B1, B2 > C1, C2, C3 : Amethod1 / Bmethod1 > Cmethod2`

then classA and classB are parents of classC, so in the machine:

`{"classA, classB > classC" : "A1, A2 / B1, B2 > C1, C2, C3","Amethod / Bmethod > Cmethod"}`

becomes:

`{ClassA : [A1, A2],[Amethod], ClassB : [B1, B2],[Bmethod], ClassC(ClassA, ClassB) : [C1, C2, C3], [Cmethod]}`

At least, that's what I'm trying to get done. I have somewhat of a design problem preventing me from implementing it in a straightforward way. That is, Class_Dict (the object encapsulating the specs for one class) is not iterable, so once i do the transformation of applying inheritance rules, i cant simply do

```
#psuedocode
del class_container[old entry]
class_container.update(new_entry) #because new_entry is a type Class_Dict, not an iterable
```

and I can't find a way to make Class_Dict Iterable, because its a single thing. I suppose I could shoehorn it into an iterable by giving it the **iter** and **next** methods, without implementing meaningful functionality for them.

There is also a second issue, which is that you can't resize a dictionary while looping over it (have to loop to determine which entries to run inheriter function on). What this means for the implementation is that I have to have a separate dictionary inside the inheritance function, which contains the newly generated class_dicts, then return it and update the class_container with the return value. The problem i'm having is that my code produces valid results in the inheritance function, (with the type dict), then I return these results and get None/ Nonetype. My guess is that its because I update "new" (local dict) with Class_Dict(a,b,c).**repr**(), and this doesnt actually construct the object in memory requisite for it to be stored in a runtime data structure (I don't know much about python implementation, just taking a shot at it)

code:

```
class_container = {}

def from_file(f):
    """
builds a container out of text file
containing class dict specifications.
    """    
    #need to account for lack of .txt in POSIX systems
    with open("{}.txt".format(f), "r") as file:
        for lines in file:
            #if line format OK:
            class_container.update(Class_Dict.to_dict(lines.strip("\n")))
            #else:
            ###throw an error cuz no bueno


def inheritance(name, attr, methods, new = {}):
    family, family_attr, family_methods = name.split(">"), attr.split(">"), methods.split(">")
    #error checking: does the numbers of ops match up. can not proceed if no.
    parents, parent_attr, parent_methods = family[0].split(","), family_attr[0].split("/"), family_methods[0].split("/")
    for a, b, c in zip(parents, parent_attr, parent_methods):
        new.update(Class_Dict(a,b,c).__repr__())
    del family[0], family_attr[0], family_methods[0]
    name, attr, methods = ">".join(family), ">".join(family_attr), ">".join(family_methods)
    if len(family) > 0:
        inheritance(name, attr, methods)
    else:
        return(new)


from_file("classes")
for entries in class_container:
    if entries.count(">") > 0:
        class_container.update(inheritance(entries, class_container[entries][0], class_container[entries][1]))
        #del class_container[entries]
        #class_container.extend(new)
```

Comment: Hi breadman0, welcome to StackOverflow. So that we can better understand your problem, can you give us the code for `Class_Dict` you came up with? Could you also provide an example of the `classes.txt` file? If you would have an text output how it would look like?

Comment: EvensF- I can do that. However, I solved this problem- would it be better I delete this post or update it with my progress?

Comment: Well maybe write your own answer so that if someone else has the same problem that can help them.

Answer (score 0):

So my issue here was that the body of my base case:

```
if len(family) > 0:
   inheritance(name, attr, methods)
```

was not returning a value. Simply modifying it to this solved the problem.

```
if len(family) > 0:it 
   return inheritance(name, attr, methods)
```

I'm interested in why this solves the issue. It seems rather paradoxical- the fact that None was returned earlier would imply that the else case never gets triggered, but it has to in order for the function to return the desired value. How did making the base case return the recursive call make this difference?